# Mechanics of an (infinite small) spring oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, lagrangian-formalism, spring

I've been thinking about creating a continuous rope, made out of infinitely many springs, with infinitely small distances between them.

At first, I developed the Euler-Lagrange Equations:
$$
\mathcal{L} = T - U \\
T = \frac{1}{2}m \dot{r}^2 \\
U = \frac{1}{2}kr^2 \\
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}m \dot{r}^2  - \frac{1}{2}kr^2
$$
But because there are $n$ springs, what I will have to do is to sum up all the spring velocities and distances:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \left [ \frac{1}{2}m \dot{r_i}^2 - \frac{1}{2}k(r_{i+1} - r_i)^2 \right ]
$$
Taking the limit to the infinity:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \left [ \frac{1}{2}m \dot{r_i}^2 - \frac{1}{2}k(r_{i+1} - r_i)^2 \right ] = \int \left [ \frac{1}{2}m \dot{r_i}^2 - \frac{1}{2}k(r_{i+1} - r_i)^2 \right ]
$$
Rearanging a little bit the equation, we finally get:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} m \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \dot{r}^2 - \frac{1}{2} k \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} (r_{i+1} - r_i)^2
$$
But here, I'm stuck. I've tried to parametrize the integral and find any antiderivative, but I don't have very clear how to do it exactly.
Is there anything I've being doing wrong? Any advice? Is this even possible?

Comment: So your final system's mass is infinite, as is its spring constant? I would assume that both these quantities would need to change appropriately if you wish to have a sensible result.

Comment: I'm assuming that the masses joined to the springs all have the same mass, and is constant? Is this a mistake? How would i solve it?

Comment: Well, what it seems to me you're trying to do is solve for a continuous system which will finally have a finite mass. As a result, you should be using the mass _density_ to define the problem. That way, when you let $n \to \infty$, there will be many more tiny masses, but the **total** mass of the system remains constant. A similar argument can be used for $k$, except (I suspect) each $k$ will be proportional to $n$. This is an interesting though slightly uncommon approach. The end result for the dynamics will, of course, just be the wave equation, though I've never calculated $\mathcal{L}$...

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133664

Comment: Keith's answer in the above linked question is quite accessible. There is also this [set of notes](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/618/lects/classMech_2.pdf) which deals with the subject as you want to, but the mathematics is relatively involved. This is a nice introductory problem to acquaint someone with field theory...